# Use mock.Provide() to Setup a delegate factory, used in the SUT constructor

Tags: c#, moq, autofac, automocking, autofactory

I am trying to test the behavior of a class, when it's passed one stub object via a delegate factory. I made a version of the test in which all the class's dependencies (except the factory) are passed as Mock objects and it works as supposed to. Now I am trying to use AutoMock to get the container to automatically create the mocks.

I am having issues passing concrete values for the delegate factory in the constructor in ClassUnderTest using mock.Provide(). (like [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37802851/5717508) suggests)

Class that I am testing:

```
public ClassUnderTest
{
 private readonly firstField;
 private readonly Func<string, ISecondField, IThirdField, IResultField> resultFieldFactory;
 private int someCounter = -1;

 public ClassUnderTest(IFirstField firstField, Func<string, ISecondField, IThirdField, IResultField> resultFieldFactory )
 {
  this.firstField = firstField;
  this.resultFieldFactory= resultFieldFactory;
 }

 public methodToTest()
 {
  IResultField resultField = resultFieldFactory(someString, secondFieldValue, thirdFieldValue);
  resultField.AddToList();
 }
}
```

Business logic module :

```
public class BusinessLogicModule: Module
{
//some other things  that work

builder.RegisterType<ClassUnderTest>().As<IClassUnderTest>();
builder.RegisterType<SecondField>().As<ISecondField>();
builder.RegisterType<ThirdField>().As<IThirdField>();
builder.RegisterType<ResultField>().As<IResultField>();

}
```

Test class:

```
[TestClass]
public class TestClass()
{
 private IFirstField firstField;
 private Func<string, ISecondField, IThirdField, IResultField> funcToTriggerIResultFieldFactory;


 [TestInitialize]  
 public void Setup()
 {
  this.firstField= Resolve<IFirstField>();
  this.secondField= Resolve<ISecondField>();
  this.funcToTriggerIResultFieldFactory = Resolve<Func<string, ISecondField, IThirdField, IResultField>>();
 }


 [TestMethod]
 public void testMethodWithAutoMock()
 {
  using (var automock = AutoMock.GetLoose())
  {
    //trying to setup the SUT to get passed a "concrete" object
    autoMock.Provide(funcToTriggerIResultFieldFactory(stringValue, secondFieldValue, thirdFieldValue)); 

    var sut = autoMock.Create<IClassUnderTest>;

    sut.MethodToTest();
    //asserts
   }
 }
```

}

I would be grateful for any indication on what I am doing wrong. What am I missing? How could it be fixed? Is it a simple syntax fix or is something wrong with my approach to this test?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Usually you use mock libraries to mock out the dependencies, not try and add mocks to a DI container because there are too many moving parts. Your tests should be very specific to that class, so you would only need to have a few (if any) mocks set up

Comment: Shouldn't it be autoMock.Create<ClassUnderTest> instead of IClassUnderTest ? What's the actual problem? Are you getting a compilation or an execution-time error?

Comment: So I changed it to " autoMock.Create<ClassUnderTest> " .
  I get a System.NullReferenceException when I call sut.MethodToTest(). resultFieldFactory(someString, secondFieldValue, thirdFieldValue)

Answer (score 1):

In your example, when you call `autoMock.Provide()` you are not passing in you factory function, but you are invoking the factory function and passing in the result (`IResultField`). To fix this, call

```
autoMock.Provide(funcToTriggerIResultFieldFactory);
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/mattwcole/c1ff12429f3f2126e8004151afd58628) is a full example of registering a function with the auto mocking container.